# MySQL virtual column and wildcard

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, sql-like, calculated-columns

I was trying MySQL secondary indexing referring to [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html), and weird thing happened.

- Firstly, I created a table with small modification per the example in the document

```
create table jemp(
c JSON,
g VARCHAR(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (c->"$.name"),
INDEX i (g)
)
```

- Secondly, I inserted values per the example in the document

```
INSERT INTO jemp (c) VALUES
('{"id": "1", "name": "Fred"}'), ('{"id": "2", "name": "Wilma"}'),
('{"id": "3", "name": "Barney"}'), ('{"id": "4", "name": "Betty"}');
```

- And then, I tried to perform a fuzzy search with "like" and "wildcard". This doesn't work because index doesn't support prefix `%`, but it can get result.

```
select c->"$.name" as name from jemp where g like "%F%"
```

- Here is the weird thing, I removed the prefix `%`, and index did work. However, I didn't get any results. Per my poor understanding of MySQL, this should work.

```
select c->"$.name" as name from jemp where g like "F%"
```

I would be so much appreciate if anyone could help me with it.

Comment: Do you just have the two test rows of data in the table? You might not get MySQL to use the index until you store enough row that it's worthwhile. Also MySQL may not choose to use the index if the pattern you search for matches > 20% of the rows. The optimizer assumes that it's cheaper to just scan the table instead of going to the trouble of loading the index. Neither of these possibilities are specific to using virtual columns, by the way. They happen when you use indexes on conventional columns.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thanks for your comment. However, my question is not about this. The index works, but the query doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your query to work, you want a generated column that extracts the name *as text* rather than JSON. That is, use `->>` instead of `->`:

```
g VARCHAR(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (c ->> '$.name')
```

Then: the index *may* help for both following conditions:

```
where g like 'F%'
where g = 'F'
```

Whether MySQL decides to use it or not is another story; basically the databases assesses whether using the index will be faster than a full scan. If it believes that the condition will match on a large number of rows, it will probably choose to full scan.

Note that I consistently use single quotes for string literals; although MySQL tolerates otherwise, this is what the SQL standard specifies. In some other databases, double quotes stand for identifiers (this also is compliant with the standard).

Comment: Yeah! It works! But how come? With the example I posted above, I also created a virtual column for `c -> '$.name'`. I can't tell the difference between them. I will mark your answer as the best, and if you could further explain it, I will be so so much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your further clarification. I will look up the document and do more googling about the difference between `->` and `->>` in this case. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Ray: `->`  returns a JSON value, so it is surrounded with double quotes, like `'"Fred"'`. If you want a string value, you need to unquote it, using `->>`, so you get `'Fred'`. Give it a try in a query and find out by yourself.